# "Ground" in electronics

Tags: electricity

I have GND on the circuit as a reference.

Let's assume I have source voltage connected serial with resistor RS and resistor RD and then connected back to the source voltage. in brief the source voltage sees two resistors in serial.

Now, let's assume I put the GND between resistor of RS and RD. so why the signal voltage from source voltage after going to RS it goes to GND and not going to RD although RD is connected to RS, so it should be there a current driven by the source voltage.

What I'm actually asking, is putting GND in specific point in circuit will lead to absorb all the signal from the source voltage and not let any part of the signal to be branched  to the other branches where I put the GND? (I mean where I put GND there's path for a signal from the source voltage, and on the same point where's the GND there's another branches to other circuit's loads)

Comment: Ground only has meaning if there are multiple (intentional, accidental, or coupling) connections to it.   If you have a stake in the literal ground connected to a clip lead and attach it to various parts of a flashlight circuit, it will have no effect because there is only *one* connection.  In comparison for something powered by the mains there is *already* a connection via the power company, so any additional connection provides a path for current to flow.

Comment: Ground is defined as 0V and does not conduct any current unless the ground  shared with other source voltages with a series impedance.  Then the physical path becomes important as ground has zero Ohm impedance only in theory. So with ground paths we either assume on the logic diagram or schematic, that these are understood or it causes problems.  Since Vdd,Vss also share ground , your application is assumed to divert both currents so that neither one affects the other’s voltage unless you have trace resistance (ESR) and/or  inductance (ESL) with RF.

Answer (score 3):

In most circuits, "Ground" is simply the point in the circuit that we want to call "Zero Volts", and use as a reference when measuring voltage elsewhere in the circuit.  "Ground" does not absorb signals, or draw all electrons away.